# Javascript to jQuery while loop conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a while loop written in Javascript for a function to clear any li items of a ul if they exist (the ul is being populated by a different function):

```
<ul id="schedule"></ul>
```

---

```
const list = document.getElementById("schedule");

function clearList() {
    while (list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
};
```

This is working perfectly however I've tried a few different ways to refactor the function using jQuery and every attempt has caused the page to be unresponsive. This is the latest of what I've tried:

```
const $list = $("#schedule");
const $listChild = $("#schedule li");

function clearList() {
    while ($listChild) {
        $list.empty();
    }
};
```

Any help or pointers to a similar question would be great thanks!

Comment: You're never changing `$listChild` so that would be an infinite loop. Also, there are jQuery functions for deleting whole elements.

Comment: I see no logic of checking if it has children. why not just to do it short: `if($list && $list.html) $list.html('');`  ?

Comment: Ah right - so instead of the Javascript example needing the while loop I can just remove that altogether from the jQuery function...thanks!

Comment: Does `$("#schedule")[0].length = 0` work?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery already has a function for that.  No need to modify your pre-existing function, instead I would just modify the code that calls your pre-existing function clearList(). I would just do something like:

```
$('ul#schedule').empty(); //Empty the entire list
```

You can also do stuff like this:

```
$('ul#schedule li:empty').remove(); //Remove empty <li></li> elements
$('ul#schedule').last(); //Get last child <li> and do whatever you want with it...
```